# How to call a php function from another php page on html onload (refresh) only (no click)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I already searched and tried all the question and answers that are almost the same as my question in stackoverflow. Unfortunately, none of them provided what I needed which probably mine is a different situation.

I want to call a php function from another php page when the index.php page is loaded or refresh only.

There is a query in my php function that check the query then insert records whenever index.php is loaded. Anyone understood my problem?

My code below on the body onload does not perform the queries in the function

```
<body onclick="check();" onfocus="check();"  onload="<?php include_once("includes/classes.php"); $empinfo = new EmployeeInfo(); $netsalary= $empinfo->getNetSalary($curr_emp); ?>" >
```

while my code below on the body onload. the insert query worked since it is direct to the onload not on the class.php page

```
<body onclick="check();" onfocus="check();"  onload="<?php mysql_query("insert into tblNotifications (empCode, notifMsg, payMonth, payYear, notifRead, notifResolve, dateTime)
                values ('$empCode', '$notifMsg', '$smonth', '$year', 0', '0', '$now')");     ?>" >
```

Please confirm first before voting negative or saying it's a duplicate. I also need a positive votes since I'm a noob.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why you did something like this? `onload=".."` you could include your `php` file, it will load on load.. no need to set onload event for php file

Comment: already used requre on php but it does not call the specific function i need to perform the queries @pedram

Comment: So the problem is somewhere else..update your question with that php function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implicitly calling PHP script using javascript's `onload` which is not possible as javascript is client side where as PHP runs on server. Try to use AJAX or there is one method which may help:

Use javascript to write php scripts and wrap it in function before `onload` call.

```
document.body.onload = function writePHPscript(){
     document.getElementById('id-here').innerHTML = "<?php echo 'hello!'; ?>";    
};
```

(It is necessary to put everything in function you call after `onload` or it gets `return` value sometimes)